# How can I get MOD in Javascript to return a decimal correctly?

Tags: javascript, modulo, decimal

A simple problem I'm working with is taking a time for a 300m run in seconds and converting them to a string so that it reads "9:99.99".  To get seconds, I do the following MOD operation:

```
sec = result % 60;
```

This doesn't work as expected unless the decimal portion is 0.5 (i.e. 60.5, 75.5, etc.).  Any other decimal gives me a result that's off by something that requires 12+ significant digits to express.

For example, 64.55 % 60 gives me 4.5499999999999997 as a result.

I know an easy solution would be to just split on the decimal and concatenate the result with the decimal places, but this just intrigues me.  What am I doing wrong, and is there a good way to fix this using MOD alone?

Comment: generally, floating point numbers cannot be converted exactly. 64.55 internally will be 64.54999999 or similar. If you need 2 digit precision, then try `(6455 % 6000) / 100)`

Comment: Read why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Interesting...I've been programming for about 10 years, and I think this may be the first time I've had need to do a MOD on a floating point.  Are all other languages subject to the same limitation, or is this a Javascript-only problem?

Comment: It has to do with how the underlying floating-point implementation works, which is usually a hardware thing. A lot of other languages don't even let you do a `%` operation on floating-point numbers, since it's kind of weird from a number theory standpoint (I've got a toddler-level understanding of number theory, however.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets assume you have a value of 921.856 seconds.

```
var value = 921.856;
var minutes = Math.floor(value/60),  // 15        
    seconds = value % 60,            // 21.856
    time = minutes + ":" + seconds.toFixed(2);  // 15:21.86
```

To do so without rounding:

```
time = minutes + ":" + (Math.floor(seconds * 100)/100).toFixed(2); // 15:21.85
```